# Reactive Extensions Buffer on count, interval and event

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I want to buffer events sent to my server. The trigger to flush the buffer is either the buffer size has been reached, buffer period has been reached or the window has been unloaded.

I buffer events sent to my server by creating a Subject and using `buffer` with a closing notifier. I use `race` for the closing notifier and race the buffer period with with `window.beforeunload` event.

```
this.event$ = new Subject();
this.bufferedEvent$ = this.event$
    .buffer(
        Observable.race(
            Observable.interval(bufferPeriodMs),
            Observable.fromEvent(window, 'beforeunload')
        )
    )
    .filter(events => events.length > 0)
    .switchMap(events =>
        ajax.post(
            this.baseUrl + RESOURCE_URL,
            {
                entries: events,
            },
            {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
       )
    );
```

The question is, how do I now also limit the size of the buffer. ie, I never want the buffer to be flushed when it has 10 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the working solution I have. Extra console.log()'s are added to show the sequence of events.

The only thing that's a bit bothersome is the `.skip(1)` in fullBufferTrigger, but it's needed as it will trigger when it's buffer is full (natch), but the buffer in `bufferedEvent$` does not seem to have the latest event before it's triggered.

Luckily, with the `timeoutTrigger` in place, the last event gets emitted. Without timeout, fullBufferTrigger by itself will not emit the final event.

Also, changed `buffer` to `bufferWhen`, as the former did not seem to trigger with two triggers, <s>although you'd expect it to from the documentation.</s>
**footnote** with `buffer(race())` the race only completes once, so whichever trigger got there first will thereafter be used and the other triggers dis-regarded. In contrast, `bufferWhen(x => race())` evaluates every time an event occurs.

```
const bufferPeriodMs = 1000

const event$ = new Subject()
event$.subscribe(event => console.log('event$ emit', event))

// Define triggers here for testing individually
const beforeunloadTrigger = Observable.fromEvent(window, 'beforeunload')
const fullBufferTrigger = event$.skip(1).bufferCount(2)
const timeoutTrigger = Observable.interval(bufferPeriodMs).take(10)

const bufferedEvent$ = event$
  .bufferWhen( x => 
    Observable.race(
      fullBufferTrigger,
      timeoutTrigger
    )
  )
  .filter(events => events.length > 0)

// output
fullBufferTrigger.subscribe(x => console.log('fullBufferTrigger', x))
timeoutTrigger.subscribe(x => console.log('timeoutTrigger', x))
bufferedEvent$.subscribe(events => {
  console.log('subscription', events)
})

// Test sequence
const delayBy = n => (bufferPeriodMs * n) + 500 
event$.next('event1')
event$.next('event2')
event$.next('event3')

setTimeout( () => {
  event$.next('event4')
}, delayBy(1))

setTimeout( () => {
  event$.next('event5')
}, delayBy(2))

setTimeout( () => {
  event$.next('event6')
  event$.next('event7')
}, delayBy(3))
```

Working example: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/RMatsen/pen/veQJvL)

### **Edit: Alternative way to trigger the buffer**

Since the combination of `bufferWhen` and `race` might be a bit inefficient (the race is restarted each event emission), an alternative is to merge the triggers into one stream and use a simple `buffer`

```
const bufferTrigger$ = timeoutTrigger
  .merge(fullBufferTrigger)
  .merge(beforeunloadTrigger)

const bufferedEvent$ = event$
  .buffer(bufferTrigger$)
  .filter(events => events.length > 0)
```

Comment: I see where you are headed with this. I tried a similar approach. You will need to do a count first. Something like `event$.count().filter(c => c > 2)`. The problem though is that the Observable does not produce anything, because there are no subscriptions.

Comment: So, you're feeding in events with `event$.next(event)`?

Comment: What about event$.bufferCount(10)? This needs a test.

Comment: Yup, I am using event$.next(event). I tried using bufferCount... It was sort of working, the problem is that it does not reset to 0 when any of the other events happen

Comment: Indeed, with 5 events and `bufferCount(2)` I'm getting a trigger on **event1** by itself, then a trigger with `[event2, event3]`, then nothing. Trying to nut that out.

Comment: I think I have it now, there's some sort of lagging between `buffer` in bufferedEvent and `bufferCounter` on the trigger. Using `const fullBufferTrigger = event$.skip(1).bufferCount(2)` give right behavior for this trigger, however the timer trigger isn't working for me as yet.

Comment: it bothers me that `bufferWhen` works, but `buffer` does not :) A very good solution though

Comment: I think using `race` is fundamentally flawed in this scenario, because it selects the first observable that emits and sticks to it. bufferWhen overcomes the problem by invoking the function each event, so repeats the race each event (is it inefficient?). I was actually checking out `buffer(fullBufferTrigger.merge(timeoutTrigger).merge(beforeunloadTrigger))`, which is more what you were aiming for.

Comment: Yeah, that does seem to work very well :) Add it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

One thing that bothers me about the solution using ***independent triggers*** is that `fullBufferTrigger` doesn't know when `timeoutTrigger` has emitted one of it's buffered values, so given the right event sequence, fullBuffer will trigger early when following timeout.

Ideally, would want `fullBufferTrigger` to reset when `timeoutTrigger` fires, but that proves tricky to do.

### Using `bufferTime()`

In RxJS v4 there was an operator `bufferWithTimeOrCount(timeSpan, count, [scheduler])`, which in RxJS v5 was rolled up into an additional signature of `bufferTime()` (arguably a mistake from the perspective of clarity).

```
bufferTime<T>(
  bufferTimeSpan: number, 
  bufferCreationInterval: number, 
  maxBufferSize: number, 
  scheduler?: IScheduler
): OperatorFunction<T, T[]>;
```

The only remaining question is how to incorporate the `window.beforeunload` trigger. Looking at the source code for `bufferTime`, it should flush it's buffer when receiving `onComplete`.
So, we can handle `window.beforeunload` by sending an onComplete to the buffered event stream.

The spec for bufferTime does not have an explicit test for onComplete, but I think I've managed to put one together.

Notes:

- the timeout is set large to take it out of the picture for the test.
- the source event stream is not affected, to illustrate event8 is added but never emits because the window is destroyed before it occurs.
- to see the output stream ***without*** the beforeunloadTrigger, comment out the line that emits onComplete. Event7 is in the buffer, but will not emit.

Test:

```
const bufferPeriodMs = 7000  // Set high for this test
const bufferSize = 2
const event$ = new Rx.Subject()

/*
  Create bufferedEvent$
*/
const bufferedEvent$ = event$
  .bufferTime(bufferPeriodMs, null, bufferSize)
  .filter(events => events.length > 0)
const subscription = bufferedEvent$.subscribe(console.log)  

/*
  Simulate window destroy
*/
const destroy = setTimeout( () => {
  subscription.unsubscribe()
}, 4500)

/*
  Simulate Observable.fromEvent(window, 'beforeunload')
*/
const beforeunloadTrigger = new Rx.Subject()
// Comment out the following line, observe that event7 does not emit
beforeunloadTrigger.subscribe(x=> event$.complete())
setTimeout( () => {
  beforeunloadTrigger.next('unload')
}, 4400)

/*
  Test sequence
  Event stream:        '(123)---(45)---6---7-----8--|'
  Destroy window:      '-----------------------x'
  window.beforeunload: '---------------------y'
  Buffered output:     '(12)---(34)---(56)---7'
*/
event$.next('event1')
event$.next('event2')
event$.next('event3')
setTimeout( () => { event$.next('event4'); event$.next('event5') }, 1000)
setTimeout( () => { event$.next('event6') }, 3000)
setTimeout( () => { event$.next('event7') }, 4000)
setTimeout( () => { event$.next('event8') }, 5000)
```

Working example: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/RMatsen/pen/yPBMgj)

Comment: thanks! their doc is really unclear! such a wast of time